# Mobile showing version of desktop website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://www.thirdavenuespa.com/

Can someone please point me in the right direction for figuring out why this page seemingly shows 2 versions of the same content?  When viewed on a mobile device you will see the content repeated, once in proper mobile formatting and then again as the desktop version.

This is from the main header image down to the "Aveda" logo.

If I add some test text to that section, it only shows in the mobile formatted version, and the desktop version just stays the same. There is only one copy of this content in the page!

```
<!--banner-->
<div class="banner">
 <img src="images/banner.jpg" width="1200" height="698" alt="">
 <div class="banwrap">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="baninfo">

<h1>Refined <span style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; font-weight: regular;">&</span> Distinct</h1>
 <div align="center"><p style="font-size: 20px;">stimulate . nurture . educate</p></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--banner ends-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one of you're instagram photo's pulling through from you're instagram feed. It looks a little strange, just because it's a photo of the desktop version of your site.

Answer (score 0):

In your image gallery there is an image of the website. A screen shot. That's what is making it appear as the site is repeated. You have the site. Then a photo of the site.